# Android ProGuard "java.lang.nosuchfielderror: Toast"  exception

Tags: java, android, proguard

I obfuscated my Android app with ProGuard and when trying to run my obfuscated .apk it throws:

> java.lang.nosuchfielderror: Toast

This is my proguard.cfg file:

```
<!-- language: lang-none -->

    -injars      bin/classes //injars
    -injars      libs   //injars
    -outjars     bin/classes-processed.jar
    -optimizationpasses 1
    -dontusemixedcaseclassnames
    -dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
    -dontpreverify
    -verbose
    -allowaccessmodification
    -keepattributes *Annotation*
    -optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*
    -printmapping D:/out.map
    -renamesourcefileattribute ProGuard
    -keepattributes Exceptions,InnerClasses,Signature,Deprecated,
        SourceFile,LineNumberTable,*Annotation*,EnclosingMethod
    -libraryjars C:/Program Files/Android/android-sdk/platforms/android
        12/android.jar    
    -dontwarn android.support.**
    -dontwarn com.android.**
    -dontwarn com.google.**
    -dontwarn org.apache.** 
    -keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
    -keep public class * extends android.app.Application
    -keep public class * extends android.app.Service
    -keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
    -keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
    -keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
    -keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
    -keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
    -keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
        native <methods>;
    }

    -keepclasseswithmembers class * {
        public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
    }

    -keepclasseswithmembers class * {
        public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
    }

    -keepclassmembers class *.R$ {
        public static <fields>;
    }

    -keepclassmembers enum * {
        public static **[] values();
        public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
    }

    -keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
        public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
    }   

    -keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
        public void *On*Click(android.view.View);
       public void *on*Click(android.view.View);
    }

    -keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {
        static final long serialVersionUID;
        private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
        private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
        private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
        java.lang.Object writeReplace();
        java.lang.Object readResolve();
    }
```

Comment: You forgot your proguard.cfg file please add it before other downvote this question.

Answer (score 4):

It appears you are using ACRA for error reporting. I ran into the same issue, found the answer here:http://code.google.com/p/acra/issues/detail?id=22

the solution is to add

`-keep class org.acra.ReportingInteractionMode { *; }`

to your proguard config file

Comment: On Acra website you can find the full explanation:
https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/Proguard

Comment: I tried the answer's solution, but it didn't work, so I followed the instructions in the [link](http://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/Proguard) Yoann Hercouet provided and it worked.